# IDO not working properly when provided with initial file

Tags: emacs

IDO works fine in my emacs setup except when I try to run a command that provides a default file, like `diff` or `tag-search` or even `load-file`. Here's a gif that explains the problem better than I do:

[image: Problem]

When I run one of the commands mentioned above I can't even press enter or try to drop to regular `find-file`. List of packages I have:

- auto-complete
- find-file-in-project
- ido-hacks
- ido-ubiquitous
- ido-vertical-mode
- idomenu
- smex
- powerline

Comment: Sorry, it's not yet clear from the gif what the problem is.  Are you saying you're having trouble selecting the file you want?  What seems to be getting in the way?

Comment: Yes, I can't select files or change directories when a default file is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate `ido-everywhere`:

```
(ido-everywhere 1)
```

It makes a difference when, for instance, using 'ediff'.

(If that does not work, something migth be going on with some of your other packages)

Comment: That solves it! I somehow had `(setq ido-anywhere t)` instead of that.